# После обфускации скрипта не распознаётся кирилица

Tags: python

Есть скрипт, после обфускации которого, кирилица выводиться криво. Пробовал менять кодировку так:

```
sys.stdout.reconfigure(encoding='utf-8')
```

Также выводить в байтах:

```
sys.stdout.buffer.write('текст'.encode('utf8'))
```

Ничего не работает, подскажите как решить пожалуйста.
Пример вывода:

```
>>> Р’РІРµРґРёС‚Рµ РїСѓС‚СЊ РґРѕ РїР°РїРєРё СЃ РєСѓРєР°РјРё -->
```

Использую pyarmor

Comment: какая у вас кодировка необфусцированного файла `.py` ?

Comment: как это проверить?

Comment: откройте в блокноте, справа снизу будет написана кодировка файла

Comment: utf 8 .........

Comment: тогда причин я не знаю.